# Where can i get the latest typed dependency list for the Stanford parser (v 3.6.0)?

Tags: stanford-nlp

Have observed new typed dependencies like "compound","case",etc appearing in the SemanticGraph when the code is run for stanford corenlp v3.6 as compared to the stanford corenlp v3.5, so i need the complete list of typed dependencies added for the latest version and also the dependencies which were deprecated from the previous versions.

Answer (score 0):

Since version 3.6, CoreNLP outputs trees in the new Universal Dependencies representation, which is documented [here](http://universaldependencies.org).

We also have a [migration guide](http://universaldependencies.org/docs/en/overview/migration-guidelines.html), which explains how the relations changed (the part on enhanced dependencies is slightly outdated; take a look at [this paper](http://nlp.stanford.edu/~sebschu/pubs/schuster-manning-lrec2016.pdf) for a more recent discussion of the enhanced representation).